# iPhone - make a tableView UIimageview footer static (appear all the time)

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

i used the ib to create a `uiimageview` `footer` in the `tableview`, i want that the image will appear all the time while rolling and not just when rolling to the end of the table, 
is there a way to d that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but your view hierarchy will need to change.

You will need to make the view controller a subclass of `UIViewController`, and a delegate for `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

In this arrangement, you have a normal view controller, with a base view that remains static. You add a `UITableView` to that view, and depending on the size & placement you can have that base view showing at either top or bottom (or both).

Connect up your table-view to an outlet in the controller, set it's data source and delegate to the files-owner, and use the same delegate methods that a normal `UITableViewController` does.

One thing I've noticed is that a `UITableViewController` will automagically deselect any selected cell (either as the table disappears or reappears, I forget which). You will just have to manage that in:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

or in
`- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`.

Answer (score 1):

No, the footer is part of the table itself. In fact, it is part of a section of the table. The footer only has meaning the in the context of the data above it so having a footer always visible would not make sense in the interface grammar.